# SQL server replace variable amount internal whitespace and replace with one space

Tags: sql-server, replace, whitespace

I have been looking for a way to replace all white space between strings with a single space in an SQL Query. i have found a lot of references to REPLACE which works fine except the string to replace has to be exact.

how can i change

```
Bob     Jones to Bob Jones
Jim Jones to remain the same
Jeff         Jones to Jeff Jones
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You could write a user-defined function to compact the whitespace in a string, then use the UDF to UPDATE the table.

Comment: @HABO good suggestion I have added a UDF definition to my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @String1 VARCHAR(1000) = 'Jeff         Jones to Jeff       Jones'
DECLARE @String2 VARCHAR(1000) = 'Bob     Jones to   Bob        Jones'

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@String1,'  ',' '+CHAR(1)) ,CHAR(1)+' ',''),CHAR(1),'') AS Col

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@String2,'  ',' '+CHAR(1)) ,CHAR(1)+' ',''),CHAR(1),'') AS Col
```

**RESULT**

```
Col
Jeff Jones to Jeff Jones

Col
Bob Jones to Bob Jones
```

**User Defined Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_ReplaceWhiteSpace(@String NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @RtnString NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @RtnString = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@String,'  ',' '+CHAR(1)) ,CHAR(1)+' ',''),CHAR(1),'');

  RETURN @RtnString;
END
```

**UDF Test**

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(1000) = 'Jeff         Jones    to  Jones till       the       end'


SELECT dbo.udf_ReplaceWhiteSpace(@String)
```

**Returned Result**

```
Jeff Jones to Jones till the end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods of achieving this, and which one you choose to implement depends mostly on performance of each method.

All approaches are detailed here: [More Recursion–Removing Multiple Spaces](http://davidbrycehoward.com/archive/2011/05/more-recursionremoving-multiple-spaces/) By [David Howard](http://davidbrycehoward.com/about/)

Here's the 1st method, which uses Recursion. I've updated the example code to fit your requirements.

**Method 1 - Code (Function):**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveMultipleSpaces (@str NVARCHAR(MAX))
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX('  ', @str) = 0
        RETURN @str;

    RETURN dbo.RemoveMultipleSpaces(REPLACE(@str, '  ', ' '));
END
GO
```

**Method 1 Example:**

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Bob     Jones';
DECLARE @s1 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Jim Jones';
DECLARE @s2 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Jeff         Jones';
SELECT @s as BeforeString, dbo.RemoveMultipleSpaces(@s) AS AfterString
UNION
SELECT @s1 as BeforeString, dbo.RemoveMultipleSpaces(@s1) AS AfterString
UNION
SELECT @s2 as BeforeString, dbo.RemoveMultipleSpaces(@s2) AS AfterString
```

**Method 1 Results:**

```
BeforeString              AfterString

Bob     Jones             Bob Jones
Jim Jones                 Jim Jones
Jeff         Jones        Jeff Jones
```